# Spring - Can you recompile a StoredProcedure after initialization?

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures

I have a [StoredProcedure](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html) which is compiled on initialization.

Occasionally the logic requires that I use a different stored procedure.

I have tried and failed to reset the name of the stored procedure. The data is still retrieved using the original stored procedure.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is a reduced version of the class showing initialization and attempted recompiling with the name of a different stored procedure:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;

public class MyDAOImpl extends StoredProcedure implements MyDAO {

    @Autowired
    public MyDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource, String originalSPName) {
        super(dataSource, originalSPName); // invokes StoredProcedure constructor
        compile();
    }

    public List<String> useOtherStoredProcedure(){
        super.setSql("otherSPName");
        compile();

        // Error: Data is still retrieved with original StoredProcedure name 
        Map<String, Object> data = this.executeSP();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not creating two `StoredProcedure` implementations?

Comment: @Gedrox I'm heading that way but would rather not - long story

Comment: @Gedrox lots of shared code and client code needs to be able to call either procedure without changing DAO. Would that mean I'd need to create two implementations of an abstract class...? (I'm quite new to Java)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than **org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure** pls use **org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall**. The beauty of SimpleJdbcCall is that you can dynamically specify the schema, package and stored procedure names. Pls find the respective code below :-

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public Date getSPData() {
SimpleJdbcCall spCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName("schema")
                            .withCatalogName("catalog")
                            .withProcedureName("proc")
                            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                            .useInParameterNames("ref_id")
                            .declareParameters(
                                 new SqlParameter("ref_id", Types.NUMERIC),
                                 new SqlOutParameter("dt", Types.DATE));
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                               .addValue("ref_id", 12345);
Map<String, Object> out = spCall.execute(in);
Date date = (Date) out.get("dt");
return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be what you want:

```
public class MyDAOAdapter implements MyDAO {
    private volatile MyDAO currentDao;
    private final MyDAO myDAOImpl1;
    private final MyDAO myDAOImpl2;

    @Autowired
    public MyDAOImpl(@Qualifier("myDAOImpl1") MyDAO myDAOImpl1, @Qualifier("myDAOImpl2") MyDAO myDAOImpl2) {
        this.myDAOImpl1 = myDAOImpl1;
        this.myDAOImpl2 = myDAOImpl2;
        currentDao = myDAOImpl1;
    }

    public void switchToFirstDao() {
        currentDao = myDAOImpl2;
    }

    public void switchToSecondDao() {
        currentDao = myDAOImpl2;
    }

    // do you really need this?
    public List<String> useOtherStoredProcedure(){
        return myDAOImpl2.executeSP();
    }

    // Delegate all the methods to current DAO selected
    public List<String> executeSP(){
        return currentDao.executeSP();
    }

    // implement all other methods by delegating calls to currentDao
}
```

This should be autowired by all the code and the switch between the two `StoredProcedure` implementations would be hidden inside this adapter. Still I didn't understand if you want this switch to be global for all code or only for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for my own situation was to implement a third stored procedure on SQL Studio, which acts as a common accessor and routes the query to the right stored procedure based on a parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Router_SP]
    @spNumber as INTEGER        
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@spNumber = 1) EXECUTE originalSPName
    ELSE IF (@spNumber = 2) EXECUTE otherSPName
    ELSE RETURN 'Unrecognised stored procedure'
END
```

Leaving this question open for now to see if a better solution comes up.